# Does jquery checkbox tree support the ability to "expand until node" or "expand parents" when programatically calling "check"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, treeview, checkboxtree

I am using the [jquery checkboxtree plugin](http://checkboxtree.googlecode.com/svn/tags/checkboxtree-0.5.2/index.html) which works great and has good documentation and examples in the link above. I now have a situation where I want to programmatically check a node.  This is supported using the following syntax:

```
 $('#tabs-5-check').click(function(){ 
     $('#tree5').checkboxTree('check', $('#tabs-5-node23')); 
  });
```

but the issue is that this is not useful unless all of the parent nodes are already expanded. (**if the parent nodes are collapsed, then you don't even realized that anything has happened**)

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to "expand until" or "expand parents" when I programmatically check a node so it not only checks the node but ALSO expands parent nodes so that node that I have chosen to check is visible?

It seems like this is supported at initialization time using this option:

```
 $('#areaTree').checkboxTree({
    initializeChecked: 'expanded',
```

but I don't see how that can be applied when checking items programatically after initiatization.  Is this possible using this jquery plugin?

and I was hoping that I could expand multiple nodes using a class name like this

$('#tabs-5-expand').click(function(){ 
    $('#tree5').checkboxTree('expand', $('.bluetabs')); 
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$('#tabs-5-expand').click(function(){
    $('#tabs-5-node23').parents('li').each(function() {
        $('#tree5').checkboxTree('expand', $(this));
    });
});
```